# Reduction of order of 2nd order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$
Q''+2aQ'+(a^2+w^2)=(a^2+w^2)gs
$$

Where $''$ indicates the second derivative, $'$ indicates the first. $a$, $w$, $g$, $s$ are parameters.

The problem is, I don't know any particular solution, so how can I reduce without knowing one?

Comment: So $Q$ (no derivative) does not appear?  If so, it is a first-order equation for $Q'$.  (Or was that a mistake, as I think more likely.)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Assume

$$ Q'= y \implies Q''=y'.$$

and subs back in the ode.

Comment: thank you, this got me started!

Answer (score 0):

I assume your equation is actually 
$$Q'' + 2aQ' + (a^2 + w^2)Q = (a^2 + w^2)gs$$ Because the solutions to the homogeneous equation are of the form $Ae^{-at}\cos(wt) + Be^{-at}\sin(wt)$, the constant function $(a^2 + w^2)gs$ on the right hand side does not solve the homogeneous equation. In this case, finding the particular solution is easy; it will also be a constant function, and plugging into your differential equation one sees that it is the constant function $gs$.